# Получение дочернего элемента селектора this

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такое дерево элементов:

```
<div class='card'>
еще какие то элементы
<img class='card__image'>
</div>
```

Нужно выбрать элемент `card__image` который является дочерним элементом `$(this)` где `$(this)` это `.card`. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(this).find(".card__image");
```

или

```
$(this).children(".card__image");
```

Методы `.find()` и `.children()` аналогичны, за исключением того, что последний перемещается только на один уровень вниз по дереву DOM.

Answer (score 1):

Вернет элементы класса **card__image**, которые лежат непосредственно внутри класса **card**.

```
$(this).children(".card__image");
```